# ATtiny84A support with "Attiny" board manager installed to Arduino IDE

Tags: attiny

Referring to page http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695, is it possible to program ATtiny84A as well, or just the chip version ATtiny84 (without "A")? Does anybody know?

Comment: 6 years old question but anyway, tt works I can confirm, I have been using ATTiny84A-U, SOIC-14 chip.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PDF [ATTiny24/44/84 to ATTiny24A/44A/84A Migration AppNote](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8187.pdf) it should be pretty easy as there are only some differences in electrical specifications. No changes in registers or so.

The signature bytes are the same too, so it should be posible even without adding another boards.